# Do not load the categories in Category.php

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have a CPT and each post has categories and sub categories. When I enter the Category.php page this does not print any post.

```
    <?php  get_header(); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 float-left mt-3">
        <h1>Category <span><?php single_cat_title(); ?></span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pro" class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 float-left">
    <?php
        get_sidebar();
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-9 float-left">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
    <?php the_title();?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php  get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Does the rest of this page load? If you add something like `<h1>Hello!</h1>` before the first line, do you see it when visiting that category page?

Comment: No, but i solved, it was something with the permalink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the template is `category.php` (without a capital letter.

Second of all, you say you have a

> Custom Post Type with categories

most likely you mean you have a

> Custom Post Type with a Custom Taxonomy

In order to design a custom page template to show cpt from a custom taxonomy, you need to use name your template `taxonomy.php`.  Please see the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) for more details.